# Equal distance between points highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to know if there's a way to keep the distances between the points equal when using xAxis type as Datetime.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/type-datetime-irregular/)

I want to maintain the distances equal I don't want the gap that the chart has between 3 and 6 January.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    ordinal: true
},
series: [{
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 71.5],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 106.4],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 129.2],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), 144.0],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8), 176.0]
    ]
  }]

});
```

Comment: See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4447257/1426035

Comment: this is possible way http://jsfiddle.net/bqmn48ud/ without using `xAxis` as `type:datetime`

Comment: It is possible to use ordinal axis with highstock.js library: http://jsfiddle.net/yv5sc3jL/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use broken axis module and set the break to 1 day and gap size to 0. If you have more breaks you can specify each break as an object in breaks array or use [repeat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks.repeat) property.

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  tickInterval: 3600 * 1000 * 24,
  breaks: [{
    from: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3),
    to: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6),
    breakSize: 1000 * 3600 * 24
  }]
},

series: [{
  gapSize: 0,
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/8oL9757j/

Comment: Almost!!! Now I have a gap in the xAxis, between 04/28 and 05/02. 

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8oL9757j/2/

Comment: What is the effect you want to achieve? xAxis jumps from 04/28 to 5/02 because of the break but the data is connected without a visible gap (white space) - what should the x axis look like in this case?

Comment: i want to show all the X values, in this case i have May 02 but it's not showing in the x Axis.

Comment: Then you don't breaks but you need to fill your data with nulls and use connectNulls option - http://jsfiddle.net/c7tgreqo/